# Is there anyway to do this recursively in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to do a custom fractal

[image: this is my fractal]

what I did is create a circle with radius R, Let's say that we have 3 smaller circles inside that touch the bigger one, They are all the same size, I wanted to find the radius of the small circles in function of the radius of the big circle

I could work out the formula and with a function that finds the radius :

```
def formula(R):
    return ((sqrt(3)*R)/(sqrt(3)+2))
```

I can explain it if someone needs it

what I want to do now is to write a recursive function that does this for each one of the small circles again with pygame

Comment: Sure. Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe formula in this answer will help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1856839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the normalized vectors, from an origin (0, 0) to the corner points of an [Equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle):

```py
sin60 = math.sin(math.pi/3) # math.sqrt(3) / 2
tri_pt = [[-sin60, 0.5], [sin60, 0.5], [0, -1]]
```

Use the formula presented in ["Radius of inner circles given radius of outer circle and number of inner circles in circular fractal"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856807/radius-of-inner-circles-given-radius-of-outer-circle-and-number-of-inner-circles/1856839#1856839), to calculate the radius of the inner circles and the distance from the center to the center points of the inner circles:

```py
in_r     = radius * math.sin(math.pi/3) / (math.sin(math.pi/3)+1)
in_cpt_d = radius - in_r
```

Calculate the center points of the inner circles in a loop:

```py
colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0)]

for pt, color in zip(tri_pt, colors):
    in_cpt = (cpt[0] + pt[0] * in_cpt_d), (cpt[1] + pt[1] * in_cpt_d)

    pygame.draw.circle(window, color, (round(in_cpt[0]), round(in_cpt[1])), round(in_r), 1)
```

See the example wich uses a recursive function:

[image]

```py
import pygame, math

def innerCircles(cpt, radius, depth):
    if depth == 4:
        return

    sin60    = math.sin(math.pi/3) # math.sqrt(3) / 2
    tri_pt   = [[-sin60, 0.5], [sin60, 0.5], [0, -1]]
    in_r     = radius * sin60 / (sin60+1)
    in_cpt_d = radius - in_r

    colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0)]
    for pt, color in zip(tri_pt, colors):
        in_cpt = (cpt[0] + pt[0] * in_cpt_d), (cpt[1] + pt[1] * in_cpt_d)
        pygame.draw.circle(wnd, color, (round(in_cpt[0]), round(in_cpt[1])), round(in_r), 1)
        innerCircles(in_cpt, in_r, depth+1)

pygame.init()
wnd = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    wnd.fill(0)
    cpt = (250, 250)
    radius = 200
    pygame.draw.circle(wnd, (255, 255, 255), cpt, radius+1, 3)
    innerCircles(cpt, radius, 0)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what do you mean by normalized vectors ?

Answer (score 2):

As something of a snack/exercise, I implemented this as an interactive toy with React (using @Yevhenii M.'s answer's formula for the radius calculation). (Scroll down and hit "Run" to see it in action!)

The meat of the fractal is (naturally) in the `drawFractal` function; you should probably be able to adapt it into Python/PyGame, substituting `drawCircle` for whatever draws circles in your framework.

```js
const nextRadius = (r1, n) =>
  (r1 * Math.sin(Math.PI / n)) / (1 + Math.sin(Math.PI / n));

function drawFractal(
  circleStyle,
  levels,
  branches,
  startRadius,
  anglePerLevel
) {
  const circles = [];
  function drawCircle(cx, cy, r, transform = null) {
    circles.push(
      <circle cx={cx} cy={cy} r={r} style={circleStyle} key={circles.length} />
    );
  }
  function drawLevel(centerX, centerY, lastRadius, n, levelsLeft) {
    const radius = nextRadius(lastRadius, n);
    const distance = lastRadius - radius;
    const level = levels - levelsLeft;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      const angle = (i / n + level * anglePerLevel) * Math.PI * 2;
      const x = Math.sin(angle) * distance;
      const y = Math.cos(angle) * distance;
      drawCircle(centerX + x, centerY + y, radius);
      if (levelsLeft > 0) {
        drawLevel(centerX + x, centerY + y, radius, n, levelsLeft - 1);
      }
    }
  }
  drawCircle(0, 0, startRadius);
  drawLevel(0, 0, startRadius, branches, levels);
  return circles;
}

function App() {
  const [branches, setBranches] = React.useState(3);
  const [levels, setLevels] = React.useState(3);
  const [twist, setTwist] = React.useState(0);
  const contents = drawFractal(
    {
      fill: "none",
      stroke: "red",
      strokeWidth: 1
    },
    levels,
    branches,
    250,
    twist
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        Branches
        <input
          type="range"
          min={1}
          max={15}
          value={branches}
          onInput={e => setBranches(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Levels
        <input
          type="range"
          min={1}
          max={7}
          value={levels}
          onInput={e => setLevels(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Twist
        <input
          type="range"
          min={-1}
          max={1}
          step={0.001}
          value={twist}
          onInput={e => setTwist(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
        />
      </label>
      <hr />
      <svg
        viewbox="0 0 1000 1000"
        width={500}
        height={500}
        style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      >
        <g transform="translate(250 250)">{contents}</g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```